# AVAudioRecorder sensitivity increase

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiorecorder

I am making an app where I need to hear very faint sounds in a room using iPhone's built in mic.

How can I make AVAudioRecorder more sensitive to small or faint noises? Any recommendations of settings I need to use?

Currently I am using this to start my AVAudioRecorder

```
 NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:str2];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityHigh],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    }

    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        [audioRecorder record];
    }
```

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this one? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the below property for **AVAudioRecorder**

```
 - (float)peakPowerForChannel:(NSUInteger)channelNumber
```

The current peak power, in decibels, for the sound being recorded. A return value of 0 dB indicates full scale, or maximum power; a return value of -160 dB indicates minimum power (that is, near silence).

If the signal provided to the audio recorder exceeds ±full scale, then the return value may exceed 0 (that is, it may enter the positive range).

[Check Link For More Info](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_16)

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get it. How do you use this function? and how does it increase the sensitivity of the recording? I mean this function only tells what the recording power, right?

Comment: What I am trying to do is record very faint noises in the room.